# Sharing data between 2 websites at client side

Tags: angular, cookies, sessionstorage

I have an Angular 2 application which has authentication process defined. I'm developing an other application which don't need any registration/authentication process. However, if someone logged in at my first application, I need to show his name/email in my second application if he browses.  So only way to achieve this is by storing logged in user details at client side and retrieving the same from other website. However SessionStorage/LocalStorage/Cookies are not helping me as they are specific to the domain/site from which they get created. so if i store in localstorage, i cannot read from diff domain.

Comment: how can you tell if a particular user is the same person on both sites?

Comment: If the two applications are sitting on the same browser (but different window/tab), I think you can look into how SSO works to complete this task.